# Proving a condition on a cont-differentiable function on positive real numbers.

Tags: calculus, functions

Let f be a continuously differentiable function on [0,infinity) such that $f '(x) \le f(x)$ for all $x$.Suppose $f(0)=5$. Show that $f(x) \le 5e^{x} ~~\forall x$.

I am not getting how we will proceed with this one.Can anyone plz help me to figure it out (I tried using mean value theorem but to no avail).Thanks.

Comment: Should that be $f(0) = .5$? Otherwise, $f(0) = 5 > 1 = e^{0}$...

Comment: done it right...sorry for the typo...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that we have
$$f'(x) - f(x) \leq 0 \implies e^{-x}\left(f'(x) - f(x)\right) \leq 0\implies \dfrac{d}{dx}\left(f(x) e^{-x}\right) \leq 0$$
Hence, $f(x) e^{-x}$ is a decreasing function. Hence,
$$f(x) e^{-x} \leq f(0)e^{-0} = f(0) = 5 \implies f(x) \leq 5 e^x$$

Comment: thanks for your feedback... :)

Answer (score 1):

Let $g(x) = e^{-x}f(x)$. Then $g'(x) = e^{-x}(f'(x)-f(x))$. Since $g'(x) \le 0$, we have $g(x) \le g(0)$ for all $x \ge 0$. Hence $f(x) \le e^x f(0)$.

Comment: thanks for your feedback...got it :)