# Be $f:\;\mathbb{R\rightarrow R}$ an diferentiable function such that $f(0)=0$ and $|f'(x)|\leq|f(x)| \forall x\in\mathbb{R}$...

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives

I need help with this exercise.

> Let $f:\;\mathbb{R\rightarrow R}$ be a diferentiable function such that $f(0)=0$ and $|f'(x)|\leq|f(x)|\ \forall x\in\mathbb{R}$. Then $f(x)=0\ \forall x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Idea:

Case 1: $|f'(x)|=|f(x)|$ trivial.

Case 2: $|f'(x)|<|f(x)|$. Okay, we know $f(0)=0$ then $|f'(x)|-|f(x)|<0$. If $x=0$ then $|f'(0)|-|f(0)|<0\Rightarrow|f'(0)|<0$. But here I'm stuck because $|f'(0)|$ never is negative, can someone help me with this exercise?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A question on an inequality relating a function and its derivative](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1958283/a-question-on-an-inequality-relating-a-function-and-its-derivative)

Comment: @CanisLupus Thanks but that answer not solve my problem ):

Comment: This seems like a routine application of the Gronwall inequality.

Comment: Just to link it all together: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1645388/22943, http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1077669/22943, http://math.stackexchange.com/q/389161/22943, http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1958283/22943, http://math.stackexchange.com/q/627189/22943, http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1765676/22943, http://math.stackexchange.com/q/845604/22943, http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1930564/22943, http://math.stackexchange.com/q/399394/22943, http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1498898/22943

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We shall give a different proof then the one given in the reference by Canis Lupus.

Suppose $0\leq x<1$, then by the mean value theorem we see that
\begin{align}
|f(x)| =&\ |f(x)-f(0)| = |f'(\xi_1)||x| \leq |f(\xi_1)||x|\\
\leq&\ |f'(\xi_2)||\xi_1||x| \leq |f(\xi_2)||\xi_1||x|\\
\leq&\ \ldots \leq |f(\xi_{n+1})||\xi_{n}|\cdots|\xi_1||x|
\end{align} 
where $0\leq \xi_{n+1} \leq \xi_n\leq x$ for all $n$ which means
\begin{align}
|f(x)| \leq |f(\xi_{n+1})||x|^{n+1} \leq M|x|^{n+1}\rightarrow 0 
\end{align} 
as $n\rightarrow \infty$. Thus, it follows $f \equiv 0$ on $[0, 1]$.

Next, define $g(x) = f(x+1)$ and observe that $g(0) = f(1) = 0$ and
\begin{align}
|g'(x)| = |f'(x+1)| \leq |f(x+1)| = |g(x)|. 
\end{align} 
By the above argument we see that $g \equiv 0$ on $[0, 1]$ which means $f(x) \equiv 0$ on $[1, 2]$.

Hence it follows $f \equiv 0$ on $[0, \infty)$.

Note: The proof is exactly the same for $(-\infty, 0]$.

Comment: One question @Jacky Chong  can you explain with more detail this line: $|f(x)-f(0)|=|f'(\xi_1)||x|$

Comment: It's just the mean value theorem.

Comment: @jacky chong why is $f(1)=0$ in your proof? how is that deduced?

Comment: @capo, by continuity of $f$.